# Write a program send signal and connect to opc ua server

Tags: opc-ua

I am new to opc ua. I need a signal simulator and connect it/send data to opc ua server.
I am thinking to write a program as the signal simulator or if there is a recommendation for existing simulator. The requirements for simulator is sending some signals simulating a production line. Signal examples includes packing_package_started, packing_package_finished, sending_package_start, sending_package_finished.... As you can see, those signals need to follow a specific order. I am thinking to write a python program(or nodejs program, it can be other languages) to generate these signals, but I don't know if it is possible and easy to connect this python program to the opc ua server? Or if there is an existing simulator that I can configure and send data to opcua server?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a simulation client for that but if python work for you fine you can use the [asyncio-opcua](https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-asyncio) package. I think for a simple application like you plan, writing a python script should be good.

If you want something more "graphical" you can also use [node-red](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-opcua)